# Not able to create Group Using AWS in android

Tags: android, aws-sdk

I have successfully created User in Cognito Userpool using AWSMobileClient as well as using CognitoUserPool. 
While i am trying to create UserGroup Using AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient then getting below error

not found: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.ResourceNotFoundException: User pool us-east-2_WltHRFcPa does not exist. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 82a3867b-3e88-11e9-9d55-1173837f7db5)

Code for creating user

val groupReq = CreateGroupRequest()

groupReq.groupName = "ABC"

groupReq.userPoolId = "us-east-2_WltHRFcPa"

groupReq.description = "abx"
val result1: CreateGroupResult = client.createGroup(groupReq)